# Gmail sending with currently generated pdf in Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to send a pdf as a Gmail attachment in Django, which is just generated by the same `view`. For generating the pdf, I use to try this [tutorial link](https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/blog/html-template-to-pdf-in-django/).

my `views.py`:

```
def submit_report(request, pk):
    template = get_template('app/pdf_rprt.html')

    Industry_obj = Industry.objects.get(id=pk)
    Industry_Report_obj = Industry_obj.industry_report_set.all()
    report_tableA_obj = report_tableA.objects.filter(industry_report__industry=Industry_obj)

    context = {
        'industry' : Industry_obj,
        'Industry_Report' : Industry_Report_obj,
        'report_tableA' : report_tableA_obj,
    }

    html = template.render(context)
    pdf = render_to_pdf('app/pdf_rprt.html', context)
    if pdf:
        to = "kanchon2199@gmail.com"
        email = EmailMultiAlternatives(
            #subject =
            "final report sending (beta)",
            #content =
            'hello, this is test report sending mail',
            #from email
            settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
            #list of recipent
            [to]
        )
        email.attach_file(pdf)
        email.send()

    return redirect('app:index')
```

here the `render_to_pdf` comes from a custom build function in `utils.py`:

```
def render_to_pdf(template_src, context_dict={}):
    template = get_template(template_src)
    html  = template.render(context_dict)
    result = BytesIO()
    pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(html.encode("ISO-8859-1")), result)
    if not pdf.err:
        return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), content_type='application/pdf')
    return None
```

But it says error like (for the line `email.attach_file(pdf)`):

```
TypeError at /submit_report/1/
expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not HttpResponse
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you try render_to_string instead of render?

Comment: inside `render_to_pdf`?

Comment: Yes second line of this method

Comment: thanks, @EricMartin for your effort, I've already fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

However, I have found a solution to this problem. the return type of `render_to_pdf` inside the `utils.py` should be `ContentFile` like this:

```
def render_to_pdf(template_src, context_dict={}):
    template = get_template(template_src)
    html  = template.render(context_dict)
    result = BytesIO()
    pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(html.encode("ISO-8859-1")), result)
    if not pdf.err:
        return ContentFile(result.getvalue(), 'sampleReport.pdf')
    return None
```

and inside `views.py` the `email.attach_file()` need dir path inside it, so we can use our database to save the pdf file and then attach it like this:

```
def submit_report(request, pk):
    template = get_template('app/pdf_rprt.html')
    
    context = {
        'industry' : Industry_obj,
        'Industry_Report' : Industry_Report_obj,
        'report_tableA' : report_tableA_obj,
    }

    html = template.render(context)
    pdf = render_to_pdf('app/pdf_rprt.html', context)
    if pdf:
        Final_report_obj = Final_report.objects.create(pdf=this_pdf)
        Final_report_obj.save()

        to = [gmail1@gmail.com, gmail2@gmail.com.....]


        email = EmailMultiAlternatives(
          "your Subject",
          "your content.... ",
          settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
          to
        )
        email.attach_file(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, Final_report_obj.pdf.name))
        email.send()

        return redirect('app:index')
```

Here I use the `Final_report_obj` named model just to store my pdf file, we can use another type of model also.